# for loop nested in case_when() in r

Tags: r

I got xmin and xmax of each histogram bin of a data frame `df` by using ggplot_build().  Let's say the data frame of the histogram bin is called `his_bin`.

My second step is to assign the bin number to a new column `bin_number` of the data frame by using the following function.

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(bin_number = case_when(
df$column_a > his_bin$ xmin[i] & df$column_a < his_bin$ xmax[i]  ~ i
) 
)
```

How do I create a for loop nested in case_when()?

Comment: You don't use a `for` loop inside `case_when`. If you show a few rows of sample data along with the expected output, we can help you get there.

Comment: `dput` is the nicest way to share sample data. `dput(df[1:10, ])` will give copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 10 rows of `df`. Please choose a small sample of data to share that illustrates the problem, and also include a subset of `his_bin` so we have all the needed info.

Comment: Thank you Gregor.  findInterval() works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential option is to use `findInterval()` to get the 'closest match' from the "his_data" dataframe, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)

p1 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10)
p1
```

[image]

```r
his_data <- ggplot_build(p1)[[1]] %>%
  as.data.frame()
his_data
#>     y count   x xmin xmax    density     ncount   ndensity flipped_aes PANEL
#> 1   9     9 4.4  4.2  4.6 0.15000000 0.32142857 0.32142857       FALSE     1
#> 2  23    23 4.8  4.6  5.0 0.38333333 0.82142857 0.82142857       FALSE     1
#> 3  20    20 5.2  5.0  5.4 0.33333333 0.71428571 0.71428571       FALSE     1
#> 4  28    28 5.6  5.4  5.8 0.46666667 1.00000000 1.00000000       FALSE     1
#> 5  19    19 6.0  5.8  6.2 0.31666667 0.67857143 0.67857143       FALSE     1
#> 6  23    23 6.4  6.2  6.6 0.38333333 0.82142857 0.82142857       FALSE     1
#> 7  16    16 6.8  6.6  7.0 0.26666667 0.57142857 0.57142857       FALSE     1
#> 8   6     6 7.2  7.0  7.4 0.10000000 0.21428571 0.21428571       FALSE     1
#> 9   5     5 7.6  7.4  7.8 0.08333333 0.17857143 0.17857143       FALSE     1
#> 10  1     1 8.0  7.8  8.2 0.01666667 0.03571429 0.03571429       FALSE     1
#>    group ymin ymax colour   fill linewidth linetype alpha
#> 1     -1    0    9     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 2     -1    0   23     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 3     -1    0   20     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 4     -1    0   28     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 5     -1    0   19     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 6     -1    0   23     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 7     -1    0   16     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 8     -1    0    6     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 9     -1    0    5     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 10    -1    0    1     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA

iris %>%
  mutate(bin_number = findInterval(Sepal.Length, his_data$xmin))
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species bin_number
#> 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa          3
#> 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa          2
#> 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa          2
#> 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa          1
#> 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa          2
#> 6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa          3
#> 7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa          1
#> 8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa          2
#> 9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa          1
#> 10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa          2
#> 11           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa          3
#> 12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa          2
#> 13           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa          2
#> 14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa          1
#> 15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa          4
#> 16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa          4
#> 17           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa          3
#> 18           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3     setosa          3
#> 19           5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa          4
#> 20           5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3     setosa          3
#> 21           5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa          3
#> 22           5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4     setosa          3
#> 23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa          1
#> 24           5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa          3
#> 25           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa          2
#> 26           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2     setosa          2
#> 27           5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4     setosa          2
#> 28           5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa          3
#> 29           5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2     setosa          3
#> 30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa          2
#> 31           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa          2
#> 32           5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4     setosa          3
#> 33           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa          3
#> 34           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa          4
#> 35           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa          2
#> 36           5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     setosa          2
#> 37           5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa          4
#> 38           4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1     setosa          2
#> 39           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa          1
#> 40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa          3
#> 41           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa          2
#> 42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa          1
#> 43           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa          1
#> 44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa          2
#> 45           5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa          3
#> 46           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa          2
#> 47           5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa          3
#> 48           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa          1
#> 49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa          3
#> 50           5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa          2
#> 51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor          7
#> 52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor          6
#> 53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor          7
#> 54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor          4
#> 55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor          6
#> 56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor          4
#> 57           6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor          6
#> 58           4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor          2
#> 59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor          6
#> 60           5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor          3
#> 61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor          2
#> 62           5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor          5
#> 63           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor          5
#> 64           6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor          5
#> 65           5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor          4
#> 66           6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor          7
#> 67           5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor          4
#> 68           5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor          4
#> 69           6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor          5
#> 70           5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor          4
#> 71           5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 versicolor          5
#> 72           6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 versicolor          5
#> 73           6.3         2.5          4.9         1.5 versicolor          6
#> 74           6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 versicolor          5
#> 75           6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor          6
#> 76           6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4 versicolor          6
#> 77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor          7
#> 78           6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 versicolor          7
#> 79           6.0         2.9          4.5         1.5 versicolor          5
#> 80           5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor          4
#> 81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor          4
#> 82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor          4
#> 83           5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor          4
#> 84           6.0         2.7          5.1         1.6 versicolor          5
#> 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor          3
#> 86           6.0         3.4          4.5         1.6 versicolor          5
#> 87           6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor          7
#> 88           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor          6
#> 89           5.6         3.0          4.1         1.3 versicolor          4
#> 90           5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 versicolor          4
#> 91           5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor          4
#> 92           6.1         3.0          4.6         1.4 versicolor          5
#> 93           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor          4
#> 94           5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor          2
#> 95           5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3 versicolor          4
#> 96           5.7         3.0          4.2         1.2 versicolor          4
#> 97           5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 versicolor          4
#> 98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor          5
#> 99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor          3
#> 100          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor          4
#> 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica          6
#> 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica          4
#> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica          8
#> 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8  virginica          6
#> 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica          6
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica          9
#> 107          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica          2
#> 108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica          8
#> 109          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8  virginica          7
#> 110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5  virginica          8
#> 111          6.5         3.2          5.1         2.0  virginica          6
#> 112          6.4         2.7          5.3         1.9  virginica          6
#> 113          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica          7
#> 114          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica          4
#> 115          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4  virginica          4
#> 116          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3  virginica          6
#> 117          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica          6
#> 118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica          9
#> 119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica          9
#> 120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica          5
#> 121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3  virginica          7
#> 122          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica          4
#> 123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica          9
#> 124          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8  virginica          6
#> 125          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1  virginica          7
#> 126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8  virginica          8
#> 127          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8  virginica          5
#> 128          6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8  virginica          5
#> 129          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1  virginica          6
#> 130          7.2         3.0          5.8         1.6  virginica          8
#> 131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica          8
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica         10
#> 133          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2  virginica          6
#> 134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica          6
#> 135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4  virginica          5
#> 136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica          9
#> 137          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4  virginica          6
#> 138          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8  virginica          6
#> 139          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8  virginica          5
#> 140          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica          7
#> 141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica          7
#> 142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica          7
#> 143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica          4
#> 144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3  virginica          7
#> 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica          7
#> 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3  virginica          7
#> 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica          6
#> 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica          6
#> 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica          5
#> 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica          5
```

With more bins:

```r
p2 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20)
p2
```

[image]

```r
his_data_2 <- ggplot_build(p2)[[1]] %>%
  as.data.frame()
his_data_2
#>     y count        x     xmin     xmax    density ncount ndensity flipped_aes
#> 1   4     4 4.357895 4.263158 4.452632 0.14074074 0.2500   0.2500       FALSE
#> 2   5     5 4.547368 4.452632 4.642105 0.17592593 0.3125   0.3125       FALSE
#> 3   7     7 4.736842 4.642105 4.831579 0.24629630 0.4375   0.4375       FALSE
#> 4  16    16 4.926316 4.831579 5.021053 0.56296296 1.0000   1.0000       FALSE
#> 5  13    13 5.115789 5.021053 5.210526 0.45740741 0.8125   0.8125       FALSE
#> 6   7     7 5.305263 5.210526 5.400000 0.24629630 0.4375   0.4375       FALSE
#> 7   7     7 5.494737 5.400000 5.589474 0.24629630 0.4375   0.4375       FALSE
#> 8  14    14 5.684211 5.589474 5.778947 0.49259259 0.8750   0.8750       FALSE
#> 9  10    10 5.873684 5.778947 5.968421 0.35185185 0.6250   0.6250       FALSE
#> 10 12    12 6.063158 5.968421 6.157895 0.42222222 0.7500   0.7500       FALSE
#> 11 13    13 6.252632 6.157895 6.347368 0.45740741 0.8125   0.8125       FALSE
#> 12 12    12 6.442105 6.347368 6.536842 0.42222222 0.7500   0.7500       FALSE
#> 13 10    10 6.631579 6.536842 6.726316 0.35185185 0.6250   0.6250       FALSE
#> 14  7     7 6.821053 6.726316 6.915789 0.24629630 0.4375   0.4375       FALSE
#> 15  2     2 7.010526 6.915789 7.105263 0.07037037 0.1250   0.1250       FALSE
#> 16  3     3 7.200000 7.105263 7.294737 0.10555556 0.1875   0.1875       FALSE
#> 17  2     2 7.389474 7.294737 7.484211 0.07037037 0.1250   0.1250       FALSE
#> 18  1     1 7.578947 7.484211 7.673684 0.03518519 0.0625   0.0625       FALSE
#> 19  4     4 7.768421 7.673684 7.863158 0.14074074 0.2500   0.2500       FALSE
#> 20  1     1 7.957895 7.863158 8.052632 0.03518519 0.0625   0.0625       FALSE
#>    PANEL group ymin ymax colour   fill linewidth linetype alpha
#> 1      1    -1    0    4     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 2      1    -1    0    5     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 3      1    -1    0    7     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 4      1    -1    0   16     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 5      1    -1    0   13     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 6      1    -1    0    7     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 7      1    -1    0    7     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 8      1    -1    0   14     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 9      1    -1    0   10     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 10     1    -1    0   12     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 11     1    -1    0   13     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 12     1    -1    0   12     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 13     1    -1    0   10     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 14     1    -1    0    7     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 15     1    -1    0    2     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 16     1    -1    0    3     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 17     1    -1    0    2     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 18     1    -1    0    1     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 19     1    -1    0    4     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA
#> 20     1    -1    0    1     NA grey35       0.5        1    NA

iris %>%
  mutate(bin_number = findInterval(Sepal.Length, his_data_2$xmin))
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species bin_number
#> 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa          5
#> 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa          4
#> 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa          3
#> 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa          2
#> 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa          4
#> 6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa          7
#> 7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa          2
#> 8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa          4
#> 9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa          1
#> 10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa          4
#> 11           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa          7
#> 12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa          3
#> 13           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa          3
#> 14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa          1
#> 15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa          9
#> 16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa          8
#> 17           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa          7
#> 18           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3     setosa          5
#> 19           5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa          8
#> 20           5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3     setosa          5
#> 21           5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa          7
#> 22           5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4     setosa          5
#> 23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa          2
#> 24           5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa          5
#> 25           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa          3
#> 26           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2     setosa          4
#> 27           5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4     setosa          4
#> 28           5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa          5
#> 29           5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2     setosa          5
#> 30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa          3
#> 31           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa          3
#> 32           5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4     setosa          7
#> 33           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa          5
#> 34           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa          7
#> 35           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa          4
#> 36           5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     setosa          4
#> 37           5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa          7
#> 38           4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1     setosa          4
#> 39           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa          1
#> 40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa          5
#> 41           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa          4
#> 42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa          2
#> 43           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa          1
#> 44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa          4
#> 45           5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa          5
#> 46           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa          3
#> 47           5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa          5
#> 48           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa          2
#> 49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa          6
#> 50           5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa          4
#> 51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor         15
#> 52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor         12
#> 53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor         14
#> 54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor          7
#> 55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor         12
#> 56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor          8
#> 57           6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor         11
#> 58           4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor          4
#> 59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor         13
#> 60           5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor          5
#> 61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor          4
#> 62           5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor          9
#> 63           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor         10
#> 64           6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor         10
#> 65           5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor          8
#> 66           6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor         13
#> 67           5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor          8
#> 68           5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor          9
#> 69           6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor         11
#> 70           5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor          8
#> 71           5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 versicolor          9
#> 72           6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 versicolor         10
#> 73           6.3         2.5          4.9         1.5 versicolor         11
#> 74           6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 versicolor         10
#> 75           6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor         12
#> 76           6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4 versicolor         13
#> 77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor         14
#> 78           6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 versicolor         13
#> 79           6.0         2.9          4.5         1.5 versicolor         10
#> 80           5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor          8
#> 81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor          7
#> 82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor          7
#> 83           5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor          9
#> 84           6.0         2.7          5.1         1.6 versicolor         10
#> 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor          7
#> 86           6.0         3.4          4.5         1.6 versicolor         10
#> 87           6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor         13
#> 88           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor         11
#> 89           5.6         3.0          4.1         1.3 versicolor          8
#> 90           5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 versicolor          7
#> 91           5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor          7
#> 92           6.1         3.0          4.6         1.4 versicolor         10
#> 93           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor          9
#> 94           5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor          4
#> 95           5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3 versicolor          8
#> 96           5.7         3.0          4.2         1.2 versicolor          8
#> 97           5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 versicolor          8
#> 98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor         11
#> 99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor          5
#> 100          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor          8
#> 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica         11
#> 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica          9
#> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica         15
#> 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8  virginica         11
#> 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica         12
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica         18
#> 107          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica          4
#> 108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica         17
#> 109          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8  virginica         13
#> 110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5  virginica         16
#> 111          6.5         3.2          5.1         2.0  virginica         12
#> 112          6.4         2.7          5.3         1.9  virginica         12
#> 113          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica         14
#> 114          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica          8
#> 115          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4  virginica          9
#> 116          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3  virginica         12
#> 117          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica         12
#> 118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica         19
#> 119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica         19
#> 120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica         10
#> 121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3  virginica         14
#> 122          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica          8
#> 123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica         19
#> 124          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8  virginica         11
#> 125          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1  virginica         13
#> 126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8  virginica         16
#> 127          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8  virginica         11
#> 128          6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8  virginica         10
#> 129          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1  virginica         12
#> 130          7.2         3.0          5.8         1.6  virginica         16
#> 131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica         17
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica         20
#> 133          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2  virginica         12
#> 134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica         11
#> 135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4  virginica         10
#> 136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica         19
#> 137          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4  virginica         11
#> 138          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8  virginica         12
#> 139          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8  virginica         10
#> 140          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica         14
#> 141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica         13
#> 142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica         14
#> 143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica          9
#> 144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3  virginica         14
#> 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica         13
#> 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3  virginica         13
#> 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica         11
#> 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica         12
#> 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica         11
#> 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica          9
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-26 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>